# Does the damage bonus from the new UA "Thrown Weapon Fighting" fighting style stack with that of the "Dueling" fighting style?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, unearthed-arcana, fighting-style, throwing-things

The description of the Dueling [fighting style](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#FightingStyle-191) (on PHB p. 72, and in other class descriptions) says:

> When you are wielding a **melee weapon** in one hand and no other weapons,
>   you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon.

The description of the thrown [weapon property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) (PHB p. 147) says:

> ***Thrown.*** If a weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon
>   to make a ranged attack. If the weapon is a **melee weapon**, [...]

The new UA, [Class Feature Variants](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf), adds a new fighting style option called [Thrown Weapon Fighting](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf#page=13):

> You can draw a weapon that has the thrown property as part of the attack you make with the weapon.
>
> In addition, when you hit with a **ranged attack** using a **thrown weapon**, you gain a +1 bonus to the damage roll.

Does the Thrown Weapon Fighting fighting style grant a +1 to the damage of daggers when you throw them one at a time?

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67485/does-dueling-fighting-style-apply-to-thrown-weapons), it was answered that thrown weapons can get the +2 damage bonus from the Dueling fighting style. So if I have both the Dueling and Thrown Weapon Fighting fighting style, would I then have a +3 bonus to my damage rolls if I throw one dagger at a time?

Comment: Note that the accepted answer to the linked question seems to disagree that Dueling applies, though it acknowledges a Crawford tweet that claims it applies. (That said, I personally agree that it does apply, and the other answer to the linked question concurs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It is 100% dependent on whether you think the Dueling Fighting Style applies to thrown weapons; a question already discussed elsewhere

If Dueling Fighting Style doesn't apply to thrown weapons then clearly these never stack as the Thrown Weapons Fighting Style requires a thrown weapon. Below I will show that if the Dueling Fighting Style *does* apply to thrown weapons then they do stack. Seeing as how [the question about whether the Dueling Fighting Style applies to thrown weapons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67485) already exists, and answers argue both ways, there's no real reason to answer that question here.

---

The Dueling Fighting Style states:

> When you are wielding **a melee weapon** in one hand and no other weapons, you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon.

The only relevant thing this requires is that we attack with a melee weapon.

And the Thrown Weapon Fighting Style states:

> You can draw a weapon that has the thrown property as part of the attack you make with the weapon.
>
> In addition, when you hit with **a ranged attack using a thrown weapon**, you gain a +1 bonus to the damage roll.

This requires a weapon with the thrown property, and that we make a ranged attack using said weapon. [The thrown property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) shows that a melee weapon, when thrown, *is* making a ranged attack:

> If a weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon to make a ranged attack [...]

All we need to do then is throw a melee weapon with the thrown property and we would benefit from both Fighting Styles.

Note that these do not add together when using a dart (or technically a net, but that has no damage roll anyhow) as they are **ranged weapons** with the thrown property, so Dueling can't apply.

I see no reason that the damage bonuses *wouldn't* stack, the only thing you cannot add twice to a roll (as far as I'm aware) is your proficiency bonus:

> Your proficiency bonus can't be added to a single die roll or other number more than once.

---

A small note on wording:

The Thrown Weapon Fighting Style technically only requires a weapon with the thrown property if you're *drawing* it. The damage bonus applies to **any ranged attack using a thrown weapon.** This means that technically it applies to ranged *improvised* weapon attacks as well:

> [...] An improvised thrown weapon has a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet.

Note, however, that the Dueling Fighting Style would not apply because [improvised weapons do not have the melee or ranged properties, they simply are weapons used to make melee or ranged attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119926).

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, they should stack

[Dan Dillon tweeted a question to rules designer Jeremy Crawford in 2015](https://twitter.com/Dan_Dillon_1/status/647065391697522688) (before Dillon was hired by WotC himself):

> Does the Dueling Style apply its bonus to a thrown melee weapon?

[JC answered simply](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/651498920636321792): "Yes."

In 2016, [another user asked JC a similar question](https://twitter.com/Wolferus/status/740647874686554112):

> Can the Dueling style bonus damage still works on melee weapons that are thrown?? Let's say a Handaxe for example.

[The response from JC](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/743317924459360257) was:

> The Dueling fighting style works with a thrown melee weapon. The feature doesn't limit itself to melee attacks.

So if a thrown melee weapon is allowed to have the bonus from the Dueling fighting style, the Thrown Weapon Fighting fighting style should stack with the attack.

[Jeremy Crawford's tweets are no longer official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/with-the-2019-sage-advice-compendium-release-are-jeremy-crawfords-tweets-consi), but they can provide a good source of rules intent.